# Updating / refreshing custom mini-cart with ajax in Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to build a simple interface in Woocommerce where a product gets added straight to the mini cart next to it with AJAX, rather than having the page refresh every time you add an item to the cart. Unfortunately I cannot get the AJAX to work and the page just keeps refreshing.

**woocommerce.php** - *the default woocommerce page*:

```
<?php

    //LOOP THROUGH ALL PRODUCTS
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product');
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    echo "<ul class='mylisting'>";
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        global $product;

        $id = $product->get_id();
        $item_name = $product->get_name();

        if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){
            $class = "variable-product";
        } else {
            $class = NULL;
        }

        //OUTPUT PRODUCTS
        ?>

        <li>
            <a class="menu-link <?php echo $class; ?>" data-product_id="<?php echo $id; ?>" href="/wpdev/shop/?add-to-cart=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $item_name." - ".$id; ?></a>
        </li>

        <?php if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) : ?>

        <div id="product-popup-<?php echo $id; ?>" class="product-popup">
            <div class="popup-inner">
                <?php woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
    endwhile; 

    echo "</ul>";

    wp_reset_query(); 

?>

<!-- DISPLAY MINI CART -->
<div id="mini-cart-container">
    <?php woocommerce_mini_cart(); ?>
</div>
```

**main.js** - *Main javascript file*:

```
$('.menu-link').click(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            'action': 'ajax_update_mini_cart'
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            $('#mini-cart-container').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

**functions.php**

```
function ajax_update_mini_cart() {
  echo wc_get_template( 'cart/mini-cart.php' );
  die();
}
add_filter( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_update_mini_cart', 'ajax_update_mini_cart' );
add_filter( 'wp_ajax_ajax_update_mini_cart', 'ajax_update_mini_cart' );
```

The goal is to get the `woocommerce_mini_cart()` function to update with ajax. Is this possible?

I suspect the problem lies with the way I have coded the javascript ajax function, but I'm not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Moe's solution below has now been added, which has stopped the page reloading but the cart still doesn't update. Echoing some text inside the `ajax_update_mini_cart()` function does ajax that text inside the `mini-cart-container` div where the mini-cart should be, which proves (I think) that the javascript function and the php function is working. I think for some reason the problem comes when the `echo wc_get_template( 'cart/mini-cart.php' );` is placed inside the function. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Did you find a solution? My problem is that I'm setting programmatically the $locale and everything refreshes the localized strings except the mini cart. Indeed `wc_get_template` seems to be the culprit. I even cleared the wc cache.

Answer (score 0):

its following the href. try the following

```
$('.menu-link').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
jQuery.ajax({
    url : woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
    type : 'post',
    data : {
        'action': 'ajax_update_mini_cart'
    },
    success : function( response ) {
        $('#mini-cart-container').html(response);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It is now not following the link and staying on the same page which is good progress, but the cart is still not updating.

Comment: Use `add_action` in your function instead of `add_filter` for ajax request.